# showing camera roll and gallery images in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, camera

I m developing an application in WP7,C#. When I launch the photochooser task from my application it shows me all the images from cameraroll, sample pictures and media library. Actually I would like to show every part seperately. For example when I click a button it should show me only images stored in camera roll. When I click another button it should show images only from media library. So please let me know if there is any way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to customize the behaviour of the chooser.

If you want different behaviour you'll need to create the UI yourself and get the images via [`MediaLibrary.Pictures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.pictures.aspx)

See an example at http://andy-teamg.blogspot.com/2010/07/windows-phone-7-selecting-device-photos.html

Comment: Can I have some sample code somewhere on how to acheive this ?